# Python Cannot Import from the src/ Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I have a project with this structure:

```
root-project/
    src/
        utils/
            file_check.py
        main.py
        type_aliases.py
    ...
```

In the `src/utils/file_check.py` I import something from `src/type_aliases.py` but I
always get a `ModuleNotFound` exception. These are what I have tried:

```
from src.type_aliases import ...
```

I also removed the `src.`:

```
from type_aliases import ...
```

These are the exceptions:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

The second one:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'type_aliases'
```

I ran the files through the `root-project/` directory, however, I also switched to the `src/` directory but I still got the exception.

I also checked the `sys.path` variable and added `src/` directory but I still get the error:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/home/eastern-skill7173/dev/python/root-project/src/")

from src.type_aliases import ...
```

Still the error is visible

Comment: Python packages require an \_\_init__.py and this is [well covered in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: @JaredSmith "The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages" The `src/` directory is NOT a package in itself and I always refer to something from the `src/` directory but never import it directly

Comment: The `from foo.bar import baz` syntax means that you are importing `baz` from the module `bar` in package `foo`. So if you want to be able to import things that way, that means treating `src` as a package. If that's not what you want, please edit your question appropriately. It's not clear *why* you'd structure your project directories this way, that's not [the way Python projects are usually structured](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/).

Comment: @JaredSmith Does PyCharm do something to the virtualenv? Because, this syntax and structure did not raise any errors when I was using pycharm

Comment: I have the same problem, and I do have the `__init__.py` file inside `src/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the `src` directory to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path), this directory will be searched for modules during import. Hence, you can import modules directly by their name:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("/path/to/src")

import type_aliases
```